# Can I use the preposition at the beginning of the sentence?

Tags: prepositions

There is a sentence

```
To where are you going to go?
```

Is this one correct? Or should I write

```
Where are you going to go to?
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sentences like "To which book do you refer?" are grammatically correct but sound very stilted and formal; on the other hand, *going to go* is rather informal.

You could say "Where are you going to go?" (*To* isn't strictly necessary) or even "Where are you going?" if the context makes it clear that a future journey is being discussed.